# How can I set a cut off audio volume in my OS?

Tags: linux, windows, audio

I would like to be able to adjust maximum volume coming out of my speakers or headphones *without* muffling everything else. Imagine a specific case of computer game where you play with headphones on and have volume brought up in order to hear enemies' footsteps, but you don't want to lose hearing after a grenade goes off nearby :)

Is there a way to muffle audio over certain volume while still being able to bring up more quiet sounds? I have a feeling this should be doable, but have no idea what am I searching for (keywords?). I hope for some general solution, but likely Windows and Linux would have different ways to accomplish it, if any.

Comment: You're searching for a 'compressor' or 'brick wall limiter'. There are many about, but then you'd have to find some way to get it to intercept your computer's audio output... for that you'll need someone smarter than me. [I know how on Mac, but not on Win or nix]

Comment: Linux: I'd try to find a compressor pluggable via LADSPA, and add it to Pulseaudio or ALSA (whatever you are running) in a suitable audio path. Never done this myself, not obvious to do, will require lots of reading on your side. Note you'll increase audio latency this way.